# Is there any way of emulating a workout on the Apple Watch simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, healthkit

Is there a way of emulating a workout on the Apple watch sim? It would be really useful to test workout apps, health monitors, etc.. I am running Xcode 7 beta and I can't find an option for it. I scoured the internet for any hints as to how it can be done but haven't found anything interesting as of yet.

The [HealthKit speaker](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=203) at WWDC was able to do it. (watch at around 35 minutes) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that I´m afraid. The WWDC speaker either populated samples manually or used other Apple-non-public-magic.

**Edit:**

This has just been changed in the new Xcode Beta (3) –  cyril

Comment: This has just been changed in the new Xcode Beta (3)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried and can confirm this works. The simulator will generate fake data for you when you start a workout session.

**Official WWDC 2016 Update**

According to WWDC 2016, *Building Great Workout Apps*, the watchOS simulator generates fake data during workout sessions.

[Building Great Workout Apps Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/235/)

If you watch at 23:35 of that video, they state:

> We see some numbers increasing on the screen, this is because the
> watchOS simulator generates some fake samples for you whenever you
> start a workout session.

Comment: I wish Apple would give us a little more control on the data the simulator gives us, for example I find that during an outdoor run the speed (I've calculated) is always 8 MPH.